# Per-row dynamic sql

Tags: mysql

I have a database representing something like a bookstore. There's a table containing the categories that books can be in. Some categories are defined simply using another table that contains the category-item relationships. But there are also some categories that can be defined programmatically -- a category for a specific author can be defined using a query (SELECT item_id FROM items WHERE author = "John Smith").  So my categories table has a "query" column; if it's not null, I use this to get the items in the category, otherwise I use the category_items table.

Currently, I have the application (PHP code) make this decision, but this means lots of separate queries when we iterate over all the categories.  Is there some way to incorporate this dynamic SQL into a join? Something like:

```
SELECT c.category, IF(c.query IS NULL, count(i.items), count(EXECUTE c.query)
FROM categories c
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_items i
ON c.category = i.category
```

EXECUTE requires a prepared statement, but I need to prepare a different statement for each row.  Also, EXECUTE can't be used in expressions, it's just a toplevel statement. Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you should just have 1 table category table rather than a category_items table? Include all the possible categories here. Otherwise, you may want to consider installing a trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: How does getting rid of the category_items table help me perform the dynamic query for each row?

Comment: I thought about using a trigger, but I run into the same problem. The trigger action needs to be dynamically configured for each row, and it doesn't look like there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I finally ended up solving this in the PHP client.

I decided to just keep the membership in the category_items table, and use the dynamic queries during submission to update this table.

This is the function in my script that's called to update an item's categories during submission or updating. It takes a list of user-selected categories (which can only be chosen from categories that don't have dynamic queries), and using this and the dynamic queries it figures out the difference between the categories that an item is currently in and the ones it should be in, and inserts/deletes as necessary to get them in sync. (Note that the actual table names in my DB are not the same as in my question, I was using somewhat generic terms.)

```
function update_item_categories($dbh, $id, $requested_cats) {
    $data = mysql_check($dbh, mysqli_query($dbh, "select id, query from t_ld_categories where query is not null"), 'getting dynamic categories');
    $clauses = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($data))
        $clauses[] = sprintf('select %d cat_id, (%d in (%s)) should_be_in',
            $row->id, $id, $row->query);
    if (!$requested_cats) $requested_cats[] = -1; // Dummy entry that never matches cat_id
    $requested_cat_string = implode(', ', $requested_cats);
    $clauses[] = "select c.id cat_id, (c.id in ($requested_cat_string)) should_be_in
                  from t_ld_categories c
                  where member_type = 'lessons' and query is null";
    $subquery = implode("\nunion all\n", $clauses);
    $query = "select c.cat_id cat_id, should_be_in, (member_id is not null) is_in
              from ($subquery) c
              left outer join t_ld_cat_members m
              on c.cat_id = m.cat_id
              and m.member_id = $id";
    // printf("<pre>$query</pre>");
    $data = mysql_check($dbh, mysqli_query($dbh, $query), 'getting current category membership');
    $adds = array();
    $deletes = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($data)) {
        if ($row->should_be_in && !$row->is_in) $adds[] = "({$row->cat_id}, $id)";
        elseif (!$row->should_be_in && $row->is_in) $deletes[] = "(cat_id = {$row->cat_id} and member_id = $id)";
    }
    if ($deletes) {
        $delete_string = implode(' or ', $deletes);
        mysql_check($dbh, mysqli_query($dbh, "delete from t_ld_cat_members where $delete_string"), 'deleting old categories');
    }
    if ($adds) {
        $add_string = implode(', ', $adds);
        mysql_check($dbh, mysqli_query($dbh, "insert into t_ld_cat_members (cat_id, member_id) values $add_string"),
            "adding new categories");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you want to list books by publisher? Country? Language? You'd have to throw them all into a single "category_items" table. How would you pick which dynamic query to execute? The query-within-a-query method is not going to work.

I think your concept of "category" is too broad, which is resulting in overly complicated SQL. I would replace "category" to represent only "genre" (for books). Genres are defined in their own table, and item_genres connects them to the items table. Books-by-author and books-by-genre should just be separate queries at the application level, rather than trying to do them both with the same (sort of) query at the database/SQL level. (If you have music as well as books, they probably shouldn't all be stored in a single "items" table because they're different concepts ... have different genres, author vs. artist, etc.)

I know this does not really solve your problem in the way you'd like, but I think you'll be happier not trying to do it that way.

Comment: i agree fully with this. If you _think_ you need this, and embed code in your data structure, it pretty much implies you need to think harder about your data structure :)

Comment: I'm trying to design a web page that can automatically handle any type of grouping of the items, rather than coding the specific groups we currently have and having to update the page when we decide to add more groups.  So I just want to have a generic notion of categories, rather than tables specific to particular ways of grouping.

Some categories are just arbitrary assignments, that's what the category_item table is for. Other categories, like books by authors, can be automated, and I hoped to use the dynamic SQL to save effort that way.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the category_items table. It's just an ordinary relation: Category 1 contains books 1, 3, and 5; Category 2 contains books 2, 3, 7, and 9; etc.  The librarian assigns these categories by hand.

But some categories don't use the cat_items table, they define their members using an algorithm represented as a SQL query, so that the librarian doesn't have to bother updating these categories when new items are added.  The category "Books by John Smith" is one of these categories. If I had a language column in the item table, "Books in English" could be another.

Comment: I meant "you'd have to throw all these new queries into the categories table" not category_items. But the fact that there are "categories" that don't use the category_items table at all tells me that the DB design doesn't match the concept. Embedding SQL code into a column goes against data normalization guidelines. Logic belongs in the app. With PHP you could use class inheritance or an interface to dispatch different grouping queries without much extra effort to add more groupings later.

Comment: My intent in designing it this way is that I shouldn't have to modify the PHP if I have new categories that are algorithmic rather than manual assignments. For instance, if I want to create a "Recent additions" category, I can simply add a row to the categories table with categories.query = "select item_id from items where date_added < date_sub(now(), interval 1 week)". I want this site to be entirely data-driven, not require code changes when we come up with new things like this. I suppose what I could do is have a daily cron job that populates category_items using the queries in categories.